# Remove HTML tags from input before sending

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I have some chat script and I'm trying to filter the input field before clicking send or submit.
This is my input filed:

```
<input required type="text" name="content"  maxlength="300" id="content" placeholder="Write Your Message.."  autocomplete="off">
```

submit

```
 <button type="submit" class="sound-btn" id="submit_button">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
    </button>
```

when im trying to send some tags like

```
<img src="avatar/user1_13128662_tumb.jpg">
<div id="test">
demo text
</div>
```

**unfortunately is working**

what i need to do..
remove all attr tags from input or prevent to write html tags inside input because all of this data saved in database and very dangerous and allow xss injected too
something like this

```
<b>
<div>
</div>
<img
<a
<li
<ul
and all the HTML tags just keep links and numbers and normal text
```

I think all HTML tags
what I need to keep
http and https and mailto: and the normal text and numbers 
just filter unwanted characters before to send by javascript or jquery ..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply a simple regex to the onchange Event of your input :

```
document.getElementById('content').addEventListener('change', (e)=> {
    let tValue = e.target.value.replace(/<[^>]+>/gim, '');
    e.target.value = tValue;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regex before sending it to Database ,identify the tags by "<".

Comment: Use something like this.  s/<[a-zA-Z\/][^>]*>//g